# Amalgamation and quantifier elimination in existentially closed structures (Theorem 7.1.3 in Hodges)

Tags: model-theory

Theorem 7.1.3 in Hodges' Shorter Model Theory establishes a link between existentially closed structures, the amalgamation property, and quantifier elimination.

We're given a class K of structures that is closed under isos, and we assume that the class of substructures of things in K has the amalgamation property. We then have to show that any existential formula is equivalent to some quantifier-free formula in all structures in K.

The proof goes like this: Fix an existential formula $\phi(\bar{x})$ whose quantifiers you want to eliminate. He calls a pair $(A,\bar{a})$ /good/ if$A$ is in $K$ and $\bar{a}$ witnesses the truth of $\phi$ in $A$.

Let $\theta_{(A,\bar{a})}$ the conjunction of all the literals $\psi(\bar{x})$ such that $A \models \psi(\bar{a})$, and $\chi(\bar{x})$ be the disjunction of all the $\theta_{(A,\bar{a})}$, for $(A,\bar{a})$ a good pair.

At some point Hodges claims this: if $B$ is existentially closed in K and $B \models \chi(\bar{b})$, then there's a good pair $(A,\bar{a})$ and an isomorphism $e\colon \langle \bar{a} \rangle_A \to B$ mapping $\bar{a}$ to $\bar{b}$.

This hypothesis tells us that there's a good pair $(A,\bar{a})$ such that if $A \models \psi(\bar{a})$, then $B\models \psi(\bar{b})$ (for all literals $\psi$). But why is that enough to build the isomorphism?

I think we really want this to be an isomorphism, so that we can use the assumption that K is closed under isos later on. But it is not clear to me that we can build the iso $e$. How can we prove that?

Comment: I believe the question boils down to proving the following (true) claim: If $A$ and $B$ are $L$-structures and $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ are tuples from $A$ and $B$ respectively, such that these tuples have the same length and satisfy the same literals, then there is a unique isomorphism $e\colon \langle \overline{a}\rangle_A\to \langle\overline{b}\rangle_B$ (equivalently, a unique embedding $\langle \overline{a}\rangle_A\to B$) such that $e(\overline{a}) =\overline{b}$.

Comment: So (1) do you see how to prove the claim? And (2) do you see how establishing the claim solves your problem?

Comment: I can see how you get an embedding $\langle \bar{a} \rangle_A \to \langle \bar{b} \rangle_B$ mapping $\bar{a}$ to $\bar{b}$, and $f^A(g_1^A(\bar{a}), ..., g_k^A(\bar{a}))$ to $f^B(g_1^B(\bar{b}), ..., g_k^B(\bar{b}))$ for each function symbol $f$ of arity $k$ (and function symbols $g_i$ of arity $|\bar{a}| = |\bar{b}|$); preservation of functions is by construction and preservation of relations is from the literal preservation property. However, Hodges is not claiming that this is just an embedding $\langle \bar{a} \rangle_A \to B$, but an isomorphism. Why would $\bar{b}$ have to generate $B$?

Comment: OK, I think the rest of the proof goes through with this being just an embedding, and not an iso into $B$. I'm guessing this was just a mistake, and he actually meant it was an iso onto the Skolem hull of $\bar{b}$?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo: it should say "embedding $\langle\overline{a}\rangle_A\to B$" or "isomorphism $\langle \overline{a}\rangle_A\to \langle \overline{b}\rangle_B$." Two corrections to your comments: (1) It's not called the Skolem hull unless we're working in a theory with Skolem functions. $\langle \overline{b}\rangle_B$ is called the substructure generated by $\overline{b}$. (2) The correction definition of the isomorphism/embedding $e$ is $e(t^A(\overline{a})) = t^B(\overline{b})$, where $t$ is an arbitrary term. You need to check well-definedness: if $t^A(\overline{a}) = s^A(\overline{a})$...

Comment: I just realised there is one more thing in the proof above that isn't clear. Each $\theta_{(A,\bar{a})}$ is a potentially infinitary conjunction, and then $\chi(\bar{x})$ is a disjunction indexed by the good pairs, so also potentially infinitary. Hodges says that "two applications of Compactness reduce $\chi$ to a first-order formula", but it's not clear to me how that goes. If $\chi(\bar{s})$ holds in some structure, then $\theta_{(A,\bar{a})}(\bar{s})$ must hold in that structure for some good pair $(A, \bar{a})$. This means that $\psi(\bar{s})$ holds in the structure for (1/2)

Comment: for all literals $\psi$ with $A \models \psi(\bar{a})$. I can't see how this reduces to the satisfaction of a single (finitary) quantifier-free formula... (2/2)

Comment: I think i have answered your latter question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4788178/7062). Let me know if anything remains unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer:

When Hodges writes "an isomorphism $e\colon \langle\overline{a}\rangle_A\to B$", this is a typo. It should say either "an embedding $e\colon \langle\overline{a}\rangle_A\to B$" or "an isomorphism $e\colon \langle\overline{a}\rangle_A\to \langle\overline{b}\rangle_B$".

Indeed, since $\overline{a}$ generates $\langle \overline{a}\rangle_A$, if $\overline{b}$ fails to generate $B$, there can be no isomorphism $\langle\overline{a}\rangle_A\to B$ mapping $\overline{a}$ to $\overline{b}$.

To finish the proof, the key point is that $\overline{a}$ is a tuple from $A$ and $\overline{b}$ is a tuple from $B$ of the same length, and $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ satisfy the same literals, then there is an isomorphism  $e\colon \langle\overline{a}\rangle_A\to \langle\overline{b}\rangle_B$ mapping $\overline{a}$ to $\overline{b}$ (and so $e$ can also be viewed as an embedding $\langle\overline{a}\rangle_A\to B$).

We define the isomorphism by $e(t^A(\overline{a})) = t^B(\overline{b})$ where $t(\overline{x})$ is an arbitrary term. This is well-defined, since $a'\in \langle \overline{a}\rangle_A$ if and only if there is some term $t(\overline{x})$ such that $a' = t^A(\overline{a})$, and if $t^A(\overline{a}) = s^A(\overline{a})$, then $t^B(\overline{b}) = s^B(\overline{b})$, since $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ satisfy the same literals. Similar reasoning shows that $t$ is a bijection, with inverse $e^{-1}(t^B(\overline{b})) = t^A(\overline{a})$.

For any $n$-ary function symbol $f$, we have $e(f^A(t_1^A(\overline{a}),\dots,t_n^A(\overline{a}))) = f^B(t_1^B(\overline{b}),\dots,t_n^B(\overline{b})) = f^B(e(t_1^A(\overline{a})),\dots,e(t_n^A(\overline{a})))$, so $e$ preserves $f$. And for any $n$-ary relation symbol $R$, we have $A\models R(t_1^A(\overline{a}),\dots,t_n^A(\overline{a}))$ if and only if $B\models R(t_1^B(\overline{b}),\dots,t_n^B(\overline{b}))$, since $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ satisfy the same literals. So $e$ is an isomorphism.